# Show pre-selected values in the right side pane with jQuery Multi-Select plugin

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am using the jQuery multi-select plugin from http://loudev.com/ and fetching data from database and showing it in two panes (left-Selectable, right-selection). I am getting values in left hand side also. After selecting few entries from left, I am saving it to a different table.

Now, how to show the selected values only in the RHS and unselected values in LHS when I open the page ?

Comment: you can use `selected` to show items on right like `<option value='1' selected>Item 1</option>`

Comment: I am getting all the values in two arrays. One has selected values and Other has unselected values. If I am using 'selected', then I am getting array One in the RHS. But I am not getting the unselected values (2nd Array) in LHS.

Comment: Add your code here. It'll give an idea what you are doing

Comment: The code is too long. I have added a link to paste bin.
http://pastebin.com/kEPxTPjy

Comment: never mind. I got the solution.

Comment: @PratikaRana: Can you please share your solution?